# Bumblebeed and bbswitch error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a problem with my MSI-GS60 laptop under Ubunutu.
I explain:

First of all, with this laptop I had a wifi unrecognized issue. So I had found somes posts talk on that and I had finaly found a solution using Windows wifi drivers for patch my Linux kernel. But now when I launch command `uname -r` I had this result: `4.1.0-rc3-wl-ath+`

And I think it's the source of problem because when I try to run `optirun glxspheres64`
I see this log:

```
[  449.307668] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[  449.307808] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

And with : `grep bumblebeed /var/log/syslog`, I see :

```
...
Sep  2 18:29:02 fondation bumblebeed[835]: modprobe: FATAL: Module bbswitch not found.
Sep  2 18:29:02 fondation bumblebeed[835]: [   11.652807] [ERROR]Module bbswitch could not be loaded (timeout?)
Sep  2 18:29:02 fondation bumblebeed[835]: [   11.652818] [WARN]No switching method available. The dedicated card will always be on.
Sep  2 18:29:02 fondation bumblebeed[835]: [   11.653932] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Sep  2 18:36:16 fondation bumblebeed[835]: [  449.307558] [ERROR]Module nvidia could not be loaded (timeout?)
Sep  2 18:36:16 fondation bumblebeed[835]: [  449.307599] [ERROR]Could not load GPU driver
```

So, I go check why bbswitch doesn't work, I try to reinstall him, the problem still persist. So I try to download the sources and Make it.

And when I run : `sudo make -f Makefile.dkm`, I see that:

```
mkdir -p '/usr/src/bbswitch-0.8'
cp Makefile bbswitch.c '/usr/src/bbswitch-0.8'
sed 's/#MODULE_VERSION#/0.8/' dkms/dkms.conf > '/usr/src/bbswitch-0.8/dkms.conf'
dkms build -m bbswitch -v 0.8
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.1.0-rc3-wl-ath+ cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.1.0-rc3-wl-ath+ package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Makefile.dkms:16: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

So the problem seems occurs because  I have not a "linux-generic-headers" for my patched kernel :/. I have  make some research but I have not found how to resolve this problem.

I hope someone will have a idea to help me ;).
Thank for have read my post and for the time you'll take for answer it.